# create a common component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am building a common Sample component in reactjs,  based on props.isConfig i need to display a button, currently i have followed below approach, but i can see lot of duplicate code, can it be refactored.

sample component

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { MdMoreVert, MdAdd } from 'react-icons';

export default function Sample(props) {
  return (
  { props.isConfig && props.isConfig && <Button
      variant="basic"
      className="xyz"
  >
      <MdMoreVert size={20} />
  </Button>  
 }

{ !props.isConfig && <Button
      variant="outline"
      className="xyz"
      size="meduim"
      endIcon={<MdMoreVert size={16} />}
  >
      <MdAdd size={16} />
  </Button>}
  );
}
```

Test Sample component

```
<Sample isConfig/>
<Sample/>
```

Comment: Anything can be refactored, whether or not it's worth it. To me it looks like you're missing a component that takes the `isConfig` flag.

Comment: is there a better way to write sample component.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use a ternary in this case. You can use constants if you like.

```
{
 props.isConfig
   ?
     < Button
       variant = "basic"
       className = "xyz"
       type = "button"
       aria-label = {intl.formatMessage(VERSION_MENU)}
       { ...buttonProps } 
     >
     < MdMoreVert size = { 20 } > 
     </ Button > 
   : < Button
       variant = "outline"
       className = "xyz"
       size = "meduim"
       endIcon = {<MdMoreVert size = {16}/>}
       aria - label = { intl.formatMessage(VERSION_MENU)}
       { ...buttonProps }
     >
     <MdAdd size = {16}/>
     </ Button >
}
```

And

```
  const commonProps = { 
    ...buttonProps, 
    'aria-label' : intl.formatMessage(VERSION_MENU),
    className: "xyz"
  }  

 const Btn1 = (< Button
   variant="basic"
   type="button"
   { ...commonProps } 
 >
   <MdMoreVert size={ 20 }/> 
 </ Button >) 

 const Btn2 = (< Button
   variant="outline"
   size="meduim"
   endIcon={<MdMoreVert size={16}/>}
   {...commonProps}  
 >
   <MdAdd size={16}/>
 </ Button >)
```

In return:

```
<>
  { props.isConfig ? Btn1 : Btn2 }
</>
```